# Learning to use methods, keep getting error: "cannot convert from void to int"

Tags: java, methods, max, min

I'm trying to make a script that prints out the biggest and smallest number using methods, however I have no clue why my methods don't work... I placed a comment next to where I keep getting the error.

I don't really need help with getting the script to work however I would greatly appreciate it, if someone could explain to me why my method doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nr1, nr2, nr3, biggest, smallest;
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input first value: ");
        nr1 = lukija.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input second value: ");
        nr2 = lukija.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input third value: ");
        nr3 = lukija.nextInt();

        biggest = biggest(nr1, nr2, nr3); // here is where I keep getting the error
        smallest = smallest(nr1, nr2, nr3); // here too

        System.out.print(biggest + " was the biggest number.");
        System.out.print(smallest + " was the smallest number.");

    }


public static void biggest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){

    int biggest = 0;

    if (nr1>nr2 && nr1>nr3){
        nr1=biggest;
    } else if (nr2>nr1 && nr2>nr3){
        nr2=biggest;
    } else if (nr3>nr1 && nr3>nr2){
        nr3=biggest;
    }


}

public static void smallest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){

    int smallest = 0;

    if (nr1<nr2 && nr1<nr3){
        nr1=smallest;
    } else if (nr2<nr1 && nr2<nr3){
        nr2=smallest;
    } else if (nr3<nr1 && nr3<nr2){
        nr3=smallest;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: It's the return values of the two functions biggest and smallest.
You've written that they return 'void' (ie nothing), when you actually want them to return an 'int'. The code inside your functions are back-to-front as well. You need to write like "smallest = nr1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the `return` signature of your method(s), assign the value to `smallest` (or `biggest`) and then return the variable. Like,

```
public static int biggest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){
    int biggest = 0;

    if (nr1>nr2 && nr1>nr3){
        biggest = nr1;
    } else if (nr2>nr1 && nr2>nr3){
        biggest = nr2;
    } else if (nr3>nr1 && nr3>nr2){
        biggest = nr3;
    }
    return biggest;
}

public static int smallest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){
    int smallest = 0;
    if (nr1<nr2 && nr1<nr3){
        smallest = nr1;
    } else if (nr2<nr1 && nr2<nr3){
        smallest = nr2;
    } else if (nr3<nr1 && nr3<nr2){
        // nr3=smallest;
        smallest = nr3;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

You could simplify the above like

```
public static int biggest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){
    int biggest = Math.max(nr1, nr2);
    return Math.max(biggest, nr3);
}

public static int smallest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3){
    int smallest = Math.min(nr1, nr2);
    return Math.min(smallest, nr3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to assign a value to a variable from a method which does not return anything.

```
biggest = biggest(nr1, nr2, nr3); // here is where I keep getting the error
```

notice that your method signature is set to void, meaning nothing will be returned

```
public static void biggest(int nr1, int nr2, int nr3) {}
```

Your biggest() and smallest() methods should return the biggest/smallest value, and the **void** in the method signature should be **int**.